# How can I get my modal box in Bootstrap to close?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-modal

I have a modal box which I can call okay but I can't close it, regardless of whether you click on the x or anywhere else on the screen. Sorry if I'm not describing it well enough - I'm very new.

I've tried the w3 schools demo and also other s/o examples and I just can't for the life of me figure out what I'm doing wrong. Full code supplied below as requested.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <title>Benny the virtual blob</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="virtualpet.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Barriecito|Special+Elite&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/de2b0ad954.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="myModal" class="modal">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <span class="close">&times;</span>
                          <i class="fas fa-skull-crossbones"></i><br>
                            <p>"Oh, no! You killed Benny!"<br>
                               "He was <span id="dead">x</span> days young"</p>
                              </div>
                            </div>
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Benny the Blob</h1>

      <p>Look after Benny, the blob. Play with him, feed him, care for him when he's sick. But if you ignore him for too long, he'll die. How long will you be able to keep him alive?</p>

        <button type="button" class="btn reset">Birth Benny</button>

  </div>

  <div class="action">
     <img id="age" class="start" src="https://res.cloudinary.com/dytmcam8b/image/upload/v1561857600/virtual%20pet/item-box.png" alt="window for life span">
        <img id="backing" class="start" src="https://res.cloudinary.com/dytmcam8b/image/upload/v1561670551/virtual%20pet/little-board.png" alt="pin board image">
           <div id="bennyNormal" class="start"></div>
               <p id="ageStatus" class="start" ><span id="days">0</span> days old</p>
                  <img id="heart" class="start" src="https://res.cloudinary.com/dytmcam8b/image/upload/v1561725918/virtual%20pet/l1.png"  alt="health points image">
                      <img id="star" class="start" src="https://res.cloudinary.com/dytmcam8b/image/upload/v1561725934/virtual%20pet/s1.png" alt="happy points image">

                         <img id="hungry" class="start" src="https://res.cloudinary.com/dytmcam8b/image/upload/v1561725898/virtual%20pet/h1.png" alt="hunger points image"> 


                              <div id="tasks">
                                   <img id="medicine" class="start" src="https://res.cloudinary.com/dytmcam8b/image/upload/v1561857719/virtual%20pet/medicene.png" alt="medicine">
                                       <img id="food" class="start" src="https://res.cloudinary.com/dytmcam8b/image/upload/v1561857661/virtual%20pet/sandwich.png" alt="food">
                                          <img id="toys" class="start" src="https://res.cloudinary.com/dytmcam8b/image/upload/v1561857776/virtual%20pet/gamesbox.png" alt="toys">
                                                <img id="drink" class="start" src="https://res.cloudinary.com/dytmcam8b/image/upload/v1561857689/virtual%20pet/red-smoothie.png" alt="glass of juice"> 

                              </div>





</div>







<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="virtualpet.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>



</body>
</html>
```

```js
var resetBtn = document.querySelector(".reset");
var start = document.querySelectorAll(".start");
var ageing = document.getElementById("days");
var heart= document.getElementById("heart");
var star = document.getElementById("star");
var tummy = document.getElementById("hungry");
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
var content = document.getElementsByClassName("modal-content")
var dead = document.getElementById("dead");


$(document).ready(function () {


var count=0;
var c = count;
var cd = $('#days');

$(resetBtn).click(function(){
    $(".start").toggle();
     if ($(this).text() == "Birth Benny") { 
        $(this).text("Restart"); 
    } else { 
        $(this).text("Birth Benny"); 
    }});


    var interv = setInterval(function() {
        c++;
        cd.html(c);
      randomNum();
      happyStatus();
      hungerStatus();
      healthStatus();
    }, 60000);

















var health = 4;
var happy = 4;
var hungry = 4;

function randomNum(){

//pick a 'health' 
  var h=Math.random();
  //pick a happy 
  var s=Math.random();
  //pick a hungry
  var f=Math.random();

  if (h <0.5) {
    health--;
  }
  if (s <0.5) {
    happy--;
  }

  if (f <0.5) {
    hungry--;
  }
 };

function healthStatus(){
if (health===4){
$(heart).attr("src", "https://res.cloudinary.com/dytmcam8b/image/upload/v1561725918/virtual%20pet/l1.png");
}if(health===3){
$(heart).attr("src", "https://res.cloudinary.com/dytmcam8b/image/upload/v1561725919/virtual%20pet/l2.png");
}if (health===2){
$(heart).attr("src", "https://res.cloudinary.com/dytmcam8b/image/upload/v1561725919/virtual%20pet/l3.png");
}if(health===1){
$(heart).attr("src", "https://res.cloudinary.com/dytmcam8b/image/upload/v1561725919/virtual%20pet/l4.png");
}if (health===0){
  deathScreen();
}
};

function happyStatus(){
if (happy===4){
$(star).attr("src", "https://res.cloudinary.com/dytmcam8b/image/upload/v1561725934/virtual%20pet/s1.png");
}if(happy===3){
$(star).attr("src", "https://res.cloudinary.com/dytmcam8b/image/upload/v1561725934/virtual%20pet/s2.png");
}if (happy===2){
$(star).attr("src", "https://res.cloudinary.com/dytmcam8b/image/upload/v1561725934/virtual%20pet/s3.png");
}if(happy===1){
$(star).attr("src", "https://res.cloudinary.com/dytmcam8b/image/upload/v1561725934/virtual%20pet/s4.png");
}if (happy===0){
  deathScreen();
}
};

function hungerStatus(){
if (hungry===4){
$(tummy).attr("src", "https://res.cloudinary.com/dytmcam8b/image/upload/v1561725898/virtual%20pet/h1.png");
}if(hungry===3){
$(tummy).attr("src", "https://res.cloudinary.com/dytmcam8b/image/upload/v1561725898/virtual%20pet/h2.png");
}if (hungry===2){
$(tummy).attr("src", "https://res.cloudinary.com/dytmcam8b/image/upload/v1561725898/virtual%20pet/h3.png");
}if(hungry===1){
$(tummy).attr("src", "https://res.cloudinary.com/dytmcam8b/image/upload/v1561725898/virtual%20pet/h4.png");
}if (hungry===0){
  deathScreen();
}
};



function deathScreen(){

$(start).hide();
$('#myModal').modal('show');
$(dead).text(c);
clearInterval(interv);
};


$(span).on("click", function(){
$('#myModal').modal('toggle');
});

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    $('#myModal').modal('toggle');
  }
}




});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
h1 {
  font-family: 'Barriecito', cursive;
  text-align: center;
}

p {
  font-family: 'Special Elite', cursive;
  text-align: left;
}

#ageStatus {
  top: -850px;
  left: 150px;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 2em;
  display: none;
}

.container {
  width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.btn{
  background-color: pink!important;
  font-family: 'Barriecito', cursive;
}

#backing {
  width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  z-index: -10;
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
  display: none;

}

#bennyNormal {
  width:327px;
  height: 444px;
  display: none;
  background-image:url("https://res.cloudinary.com/dytmcam8b/image/upload/v1561677299/virtual%20pet/Sheet.png");
  top: -450px;
  left:250px;
  position: relative;
  transform: scale(0.5);
  -webkit-animation: benny 3s steps(10) infinite;
       -moz-animation: benny 1.5s steps(10) infinite;
        -ms-animation: benny 1.5s steps(10) infinite;
         -o-animation: benny 1.5s steps(10) infinite;
            animation: benny 1.5s steps(10) infinite;
}
   @-webkit-keyframes benny{
    from{background-position:0px;}
to{background-position:-3270px;}
}
  }

  @keyframes normal{
    from {background-position:0px;}
to {background-position:-3270px;}
}


  #heart {
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    transform: scale(0.5);
    top: -970px;
    left: 400px;
    position: relative;
    display: none;
    }
 #star {
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
   top: -970px;
   left: 350px;
    transform: scale(0.5);
    position: relative;
   display: none;
}


 #hungry {
    height: 80px;
    width: 80px;
    position: relative;
    left: 330px;
   top: -970px;
   display: none;
    }

#age {
  width: 250px;
  position: relative;
  top: 180px;
  left: 100px;
  display: none;
}

#medicine {
  width: 100px;
  position: relative;
  top: -870px;
  left: 150px;
  display: none;
   }

#toys {
  width: 100px;
  position: relative;
  top:-1000px;
  left:-50px;
  display: none;
  }

.action {
  position: relative;
  height: 400px;
  width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#food {
  width: 100px;
  position: relative;
  left: 440px;
  top: -1000px;
  display: none;
   }

#drink{
  width: 100px;
  position: relative;
  left: 240px;
  top: -900px;
  display: none;
  }

.hidden {
  display: block;
}

.modal {
  display: none; /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 100; /* Sit on top */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%; /* Full width */
  height: 100%; /* Full height */
  overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(242, 114, 223); /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgb(242, 114, 223); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content/Box */
.modal-content {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: 15% auto;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid rgb(242, 114, 223);
  width: 20%; 
  font-family: 'Barriecito', cursive;
  font-size: 2em;
  text-align: center;

}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
  color: #aaa;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#dead {
  text-align: center;
}
```

My x is non-responsive and neither can I click anywhere else on the screen to close it. There's no error message in Chrome developer. When I put my cursor over the x the link appears 'dead'.

Comment: if it's not closing on the cross, have you loaded the bootstrap js correctly ?

Comment: Please provide the full code so people can better help you, there are errors in your code or it is not complete.

Comment: I'll add the full code. None of the examples below have helped unfortunately. I believe I've got bootstrap js loaded. it's definitely at the bottom of my html.

Comment: Your close modal is not being focused when it is loaded in the browser, try giving `position:relative` to your `modal-backdrop show` class

Answer (score 1):

Use `.modal('toggle')` according the docs here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#modaltoggle

```
$('#myModal').modal('toggle');
```

But on the default modal behavior, when user click out the modal window (gray area) it is closed automatically, see this working here: https://jsfiddle.net/Lc8ayf9k/

Consider review the `javascript` and `stylesheet` references in your page

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('#myModal').modal('toggle');
```

Comment: This didn't help me. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Bootstrap, then the modal settings bootstrap.js file should be able to close the modal. 
Here is an example of Bootstrap modal.

```
`<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role='dialog'>
   <div class="modal-dialog">
     <div class="modal-content">
       <div class="modal-header">
         <h4>myModal</h4>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" title="Close">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
           <p>"Oh, no! You killed Benny!"<br>
           "He was <span id="dead">x</span> days young"</p>
        </div>
      </div>
     </div>
   </div>`
```

If you need a custom JavaScript to close the modal, you can try out this script:

```
`<script type="text/javascript">
   // Get the modal object
   var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

  // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
  var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

  // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
  span.onclick = function() {
      modal.style.display = "none";
    }

  // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
  window.onclick = function(event) {
     if (event.target == modal) {
       modal.style.display = "none";
       }
    }
   </script>`
```

Comment: I didn't have any luck with this I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the way you attached your event listeners is wrong. If you're using vanilla javascript, you should assign the DOM inside a variable first:

```
var thisSpan = document.getElementById("close");
thisSpan.addEventListener("click", function(){
    modal.style.display = "none";
});
```

With jQuery, it is a bit simpler, especially if you're using bootstrap modal plugin. You can follow the other solutions given by the fellow peers here. If it is a custom modal, then we can have a similar pattern as the previous code:

```
$("#close").on("click", function(){
    modal.style.display = "none";
});
```

Comment: Sorry. I didn't find this made any difference.